# issue on json structure

Tags: json, function, sum, structure

I have a structure in this manner

```
var finalJson = [{"values":[{"x":1444748400000,"y":223696},{"x":1444759200000,"y":7178}],"key":"first_value"},{"values":[{"x":1444748400000,"y":216022},{"x":1444759200000,"y":4996}],"key":"second"},{"values":[{"x":1444759200000,"y":572}],"key":"third"},{"values":[{"x":1444748400000,"y":2446},{"x":1444759200000,"y":60}],"key":"Fourth"},{"values":[{"x":1444737600000,"y":22178},{"x":1444748400000,"y":15864},{"x":1444759200000,"y":540}],"key":"fifth"},{"values":[{"x":1444748400000,"y":8446},{"x":1444759200000,"y":116}],"key":"Sixth"},{"values":[{"x":1444759200000,"y":50}],"key":"seventh"}}] ;
```

Actually I'm supposed to calculate sum of y values for given time frame from the json structure that has its key as fifth onwards till seventh
now i have written the code to calculate it

```
var Arr1 = [];
var newJson_forFinalArr = [];
if(Arr1.length>5) {
    for(var k=0;k<finalJson.length;k++){
        for(var m=5;m<Arr1.length;m++){
            sum += Number(finalJson[m].values[k].y);
            Arr1[m].values.push({"y":sum,"x":finalJson[m].values.x });

             newJson_forFinalArr.push(Arr1[m]);
             console.log("data found :: "+JSON.stringify(Arr1));
         }
     }
}
```

But the sum is not happening as per the requirement

Comment: Validate your json in online tool ref: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: the thing is my json is correct

Comment: I'm supposed to calculate sum of y values for given time frame from the json structure that has its key as fifth onwards till seventh now i have written the code to calculate it which i dont know whether im doing it correct or not

Comment: [{"values":[{"x":1444748400000,"y":223696},{"x":1444759200000,"y":7178}],"key":"first_value"},{"values":[{"x":1444748400000,"y":216022},{"x":1444759200000,"y":4996}],"key":"second"},{"values":[{"x":1444759200000,"y":572}],"key":"third"},{"values":[{"x":1444748400000,"y":2446},{"x":1444759200000,"y":60}],"key":"Fourth"},{"values":[{"x":1444737600000,"y":22178},{"x":1444748400000,"y":15864},{"x":1444759200000,"y":540}],"key":"fifth"},{"values":[{"x":1444748400000,"y":8446},{"x":1444759200000,"y":116}],"key":"Sixth"},{"values":[{"x":1444759200000,"y":50}],"key":"seventh"}]

Comment: the above is correct json sorry had added extra bracket